# CheerioJS get specific <li> where header text 'What I Want'

Tags: node.js, cheerio, scrape

I'm trying to get li elements where the header is 'What I want'

This is my Code:

```
let wants = []
                $$('li').each((wantIdx, wantElement) => {
                    const want= $(relatedArticleElement).text()
                    wants.push(want)
                })
```

and this is the HTML i'm trying to parse from:

```
<div class="side-list-panel">
    <h4 class="panel-header">What I Want</h4>
    <ul class="panel-items-list">
        <li>
            1
        </li>
        <li>
            2
        </li>
        <li>
            3
        </li>
        <li>
                4
        </li>
        <li>
            5
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="side-list-panel">
    <h4 class="panel-header">What I don't want</h4>
    <ul class="panel-items-list">
        <li>
            a
        </li>
        <li>
            b
        </li>
        <li>
            c
        </li>
        <li>
            d
        </li>
        <li>
            e
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this code gets me every single li elements in the page obviously, is there any way i can only get the lis under the 'What I Want' panel-header?

Comment: Don't you have any class to distinguish one panel-header from another?

Comment: No, I don't have any. The only identifier i have is the text in panel-header

Comment: You can try JQuery's `contains` if Cheerio supports it Example `$('td:contains("male")')`

Comment: It will help us answer your question if you include within it what you've tried so far, and what research you've done.

Comment: @DylanLandry I tried hardcoded it with .eq() and it works.. But i was just wondering is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @Anatoly yessss :contains totally works! I combined :contains and .nextUntil and it works perfectly. Thank you man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get those with:

```
$('h4:contains("What I Want") + ul li').get().map(li => $(li).text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try JQuery's contains if Cheerio supports it Example $('td:contains("male")')